# Wordpress parse_query issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a plugin where I need to be able to show only specified posts in the admin side of a Wordpress site.

How can I hook my array of post id's into post__in?

```
// Show specified Posts
private function ShowPosts($ps)
{
    var_dump($ps); // shows the id's
    echo '<hr />';
    add_filter('parse_query', function() {
        global $ps;
        var_dump($ps); // Shows 3 nulls
        global $query, $pagenow, $post_type;
        if($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'post'){
            $query->query_vars['post__in'] = $ps;
        }
    });
}
```

The first `var_dump` shows me the array of ids, while the second does not.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you have global in from of %ps?

Comment: You can also ask on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You are already in the function so you cannot declare global variables here the easiest fix if you want

```
private function ShowPosts($ps)
{
    $_SESSION['psvalue'] = $ps; // shows the id's
    echo '<hr />';
    add_filter('parse_query', function() {
        $ps = $_SESSION['psvalue'];
        global $query, $pagenow, $post_type;
        if($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'post'){
            $query->query_vars['post__in'] = $ps;
        }
    });
}
```

Other fix is using global keyword

```
private function ShowPosts($ps)
    {
        $GLOBALS['psvalue'] = $ps;
        echo '<hr />';
        add_filter('parse_query', function() {
            $ps = $GLOBALS['psvalue'];
            global $query, $pagenow, $post_type;
            if($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'post'){
                $query->query_vars['post__in'] = $ps;
            }
        });
    }
```